# I need help! Do you know the name of this documentary about music?

Tags: piano

I need to find a BBC documentary about classical music (or opera) that I have seen long time ago. I don't remember the name. I just remember a scene where the male host play and sing at the piano while reading a score, and then he tells that a conductor that doesn't know how to do that is not capable of interpreting anything. I have seen this documentary on Arte1 channel or People+arts.

Do you know which documentary is this?

Comment: Not BBC produced, but it could be Bernstein's [Norton lectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unanswered_Question_(lecture_series)).  I don't know whether he ever makes the claim "that a conductor that doesn't know how to do that is not capable of interpreting anything" though, and I don't know whether he would have agreed with that claim.  I suspect he would have had a more nuanced view of the question, but maybe not.